# two horizontal recycler views side by side if space, or one above the other if not

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

I have a UI element that contains two horizontal recycler views, which each show a list of icons (which are used as toggles to make choices).

In most cases, on most devices, there will be room to show both recycler views in their completeness (i.e. no scrolling required) side by side on a single row (i.e. the start of RV2 is constrained to the end of RV1).

However, if the device has a particularly small screen, or a few edge cases where there's more than 4 or 5 icons in each view, there's won't be enough room to show these in their completeness on a single line, in which case I want to show each recycler view on it's own line (i.e. the top of RV2 is constrained to the bottom of RV1).

(In the very rare case of there still not being enough room to show one of the RVs in it's completeness once they're on separate lines, then I'm ok with the RVs scrolling horizontally!)

Basically, if there's only a few icons, it looks much better if they're all on the same row, but if there's not room I'd rather split them on two rows than have them scroll.

Is this easily achievable?

Here's my current layout file, which stacks the RVs on top of each other

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:layout_marginVertical="5dp">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivPersonImage"
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circular_shadow"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_dummy_profile"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.myProject.android.custom.InstantAutoComplete
        android:id="@+id/auto_etPersonName"
        style="@style/regular"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_outline_grey"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:hint="@string/enterNameOrSelectBuddies"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress|textPersonName"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:textColor="@color/textColor"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tvPersonName"

        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/ivRemovePerson"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ivPersonImage"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/ivPersonImage" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvPersonName"
        style="@style/regular"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:paddingHorizontal="8dp"
        android:text="name goes here"
        android:textColor="@color/appThemeColor"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/rvSport"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/ivRemovePerson"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ivPersonImage"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/auto_etPersonName" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvSport"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layoutManager=".WrapContentLinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/rvLevel"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/ivRemovePerson"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ivPersonImage"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"/>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvLevel"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layoutManager=".WrapContentLinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/ivPersonImage"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/ivRemovePerson"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ivPersonImage"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/rvSport" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivRemovePerson"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_delete_bin_24dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/ivPersonImage"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/barrier2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/ivPersonImage" />


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="end"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="auto_etPersonName,tvPersonName"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

## Edit:

I've got closer using flow helper to hold the two recycler views.

```
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvSport"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layoutManager=".WrapContentLinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        tools:itemCount="3"/>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvLevel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layoutManager=".WrapContentLinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        tools:itemCount="8"/>

    

<androidx.constraintlayout.helper.widget.Flow
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:constraint_referenced_ids="rvSport,rvLevel"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:flow_wrapMode="chain"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/ivPersonImage"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/barrier2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvPersonName"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/ivPersonImage"
    app:flow_horizontalStyle="packed"
    app:flow_horizontalBias="0"
    app:flow_horizontalGap="10dp"
    app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
    app:flow_horizontalAlign="start"

    />
```

This works when both recylcer views fit on one line.
It works fine when at least one recylcer view is bigger than one line (they show on separate lines, with the recylcer view clipped to the flow's constraints)
It doesn't work when one of the views is smaller than it's constraints, but the two views don't fit on one line together within the constraints.

E.g. if X represents constraints, Y is RV1 contents and Z is RV2 contents, I get this:

Both fit on one line - shows correctly on one line

XXXXXXXXXXX
YYY ZZZ

One is larger - shows correctly on separate lines (I can add as many Zs as I like, it stays within the constraints and the Z recycler view scrolls horizontally)

XXXXXXXXXX
YYY
ZZZZZZZZZZ

Both RVs are too big to show on one line, but neither is too big for it's own line (i.e. to force horizontal scrolling). Shows incorrectly, with 2nd RV overlapping it's constraints.

XXXXXXXXXX
YYY ZZZZZZZZ

It seems like `app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"` doesn't work properly with flow helper

Comment: Consider using [FlexboxLayout](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/02/build-flexible-layouts-with.html).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can achieve this easily by using only two recycler views. You just have to change the constraints programmatically as per your requirement. Here's the sample:

```
 ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.parent_layout);
 ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
 constraintSet.clone(constraintLayout);
 constraintSet.connect(R.id.imageView,ConstraintSet.RIGHT,R.id.check_answer1,ConstraintSet.RIGHT,0);
 constraintSet.connect(R.id.imageView,ConstraintSet.TOP,R.id.check_answer1,ConstraintSet.TOP,0);
 constraintSet.applyTo(constraintLayout);
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid taking this approach, as it would involve having to calculate the sizes manually and decide what constraints to apply to the layout. I'd much rather just let the layout do it's thing!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else reading this, I found the answer with the flow helper. Some of my constraints weren't set up correctly, I needed to contstrain to the flow helper, rather than it's contents.

Here's the full file which is now working 100% as intended!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:layout_marginVertical="5dp">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivPersonImage"
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circular_shadow"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_dummy_profile"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/flowSportsLevels"
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"        />

    <com.myproject.android.custom.InstantAutoComplete
        android:id="@+id/auto_etPersonName"
        style="@style/regular"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_outline_grey"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:hint="@string/enterNameOrSelectBuddies"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress|textPersonName"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:textColor="@color/textColor"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tvPersonName"

        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/ivRemovePerson"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ivPersonImage"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/ivPersonImage" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvPersonName"
        style="@style/regular"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:paddingHorizontal="8dp"
        tools:text="name here"
        android:textColor="@color/appThemeColor"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/flowSportsLevels"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/ivRemovePerson"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ivPersonImage"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/auto_etPersonName" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvSport"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layoutManager=".WrapContentLinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        tools:itemCount="3"/>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvLevel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layoutManager=".WrapContentLinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        tools:itemCount="4"/>



<androidx.constraintlayout.helper.widget.Flow
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:constraint_referenced_ids="rvSport,rvLevel"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:flow_wrapMode="chain"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/ivPersonImage"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/barrier2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvPersonName"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/ivPersonImage"
    app:flow_horizontalStyle="packed"
    app:flow_horizontalBias="0"
    app:flow_horizontalGap="10dp"
    app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
    app:flow_horizontalAlign="start"
    android:id="@+id/flowSportsLevels"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
    />

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivRemovePerson"
    android:layout_width="24dp"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_delete_bin_24dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/ivPersonImage"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/barrier2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/ivPersonImage" />
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="end"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="auto_etPersonName,tvPersonName"/>
   
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```